# SQL PIVOT a table based on a column with ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the Table

Like

```
 ID, ID_CLIENT, ID_TYPE, PRICE
```

How can I create a new "CTE"table where I have 1 record foreach ID_Client.
And for some(5) ID_TYPE a priceType column.

Like

```
ID_CLIENT, PRICEFORID_TYPE1, PRICEFORIDTYPE_2,.......
1              10                15               
2              20                30
```

My first tought was to use a PIVOT table but then 1 released I cannot filter on ID_TYPE.

Comment: What is your input data? You could search for `dynamic pivot query` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumining you need DYNAMIC

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select [ID_CLIENT]
              ,[Item] = concat(''PRICEFORID_TYPE'',[ID_TYPE])
              ,[Price]
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Price]) For [Item] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(concat('PRICEFORID_TYPE',[ID_TYPE])) 
                                               From YourTable  
                                               Order By 1 
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Generated SQL looks like this**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select [ID_CLIENT]
              ,[Item] = concat('PRICEFORID_TYPE',[ID_TYPE])
              ,[Price]
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Price]) For [Item] in ([PRICEFORID_TYPE1],[PRICEFORID_TYPE2]) ) p
```

Comment: Oke didn't know about DYNAMIC so then you can search for a long time.
Altough the example works I still need to figure out what it realy does :)

Comment: @FrederikDeClercq Happy it helped.  Run the subquery to see the generated data which "feeds" the pivot.  The STUFF() portion will just generate the columns.  cheers  :)